# C++ tutorial assigns value to pointer without dereferencing

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working my way through Lazy Foo's tutorial on SDL and I've come upon something I don't understand. When I learned about pointers I was under the impression that it pointed to a memory address, and therefore had to be dereferenced to change the value stored AT that memory address. So how is it that you can assign a value that's not a memory address to a pointer variable without dereferencing it.

```
    SDL_Surface* gHelloWorld = NULL;

    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/hello_world.bmp");
```

Comment: There's no dereferencing needed for pointer assignment.

Comment: "a value that's not a memory address" - how did you come to the conclusion that that function doesn't return a memory address?

Comment: Because I came from a c# background and assumed that it didn't... that explains everything.

Comment: Don't assume anything in C++ is like C#. And you could have cleared that doubt by simply checking the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets compare this to a house, your SDL_Surface object is a house.
Now your gHelloWorld is a SDL_Surface pointer. So you can compare this to a card where the address of a house is written on it.
In your initialization you give the gHelloWorld an empty card.
In the next line you call SDL_LoadBMP that will give you a new card with a new adress on it. (Maybe the function built you a house and gives you the address where he built your house).